# allowing guests and members of site to see who is online/logged in using ajax, php/pdo, css, html

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, pdo

I have searched all over the net, and can't find a solution to this.  I have no experience in AJAX but know it will be needed to perform this function as I believe it would be better than just using pure javascript.

I have a list of members who registered on my site, list is on a separate page --> on that list for each member, there is either a green dot (signifies if member is online) and if the user is offline (grey dot shows).  I have that as a placeholder at the moment using only css and html.  The `<online />` and `<offline />` are within the `<h2>` tag almost like a `<span>` tag.  Is there a way to auto-update this to show who is actually logged in/out in real-time and without using NodeJS and/or SocketIO?

The html looks like this:

```
<h2>Billy <online title="Online" /></h2>
```

Where the `<online title="Online" />` will then display the green dot next to their name if online (logged in).  If they are not logged in, the html should look like this:

```
<h2>Billy <offline title="Offline" /></h2>
```

Where the `<offline title="Offline" />` will then display the grey dot next to their name if offline (logged out).

Like I also mentioned, I have no experience in AJAX but am pretty sure it's something I'd need to perform an auto-update/refresh time just for this section alone - so NOT for the entire page...And I am a little familiar with PHP, so I would base a query using `SESSION_[ID]` to see/gather information on who is logged in and who isn't.

If anyone could help, I'd greatly appreciate it, I've been searchin' for days on how to accomplish this and cannot find anything...

Demo of what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/tZpk6/

Answer (score 0):

While I am not all JS fancy, the basics of this is to simply update a table in your database with the latest time that someone was logged in or performed an action - then when you are displaying the information about users, you simply query that table - anyone in say the last five or ten minutes who had some kind of activity is considered "Online" - and others... well aren't.

Your script can't really use session IDs - as they are unique and only visible to the user who is running the code. By that I mean, that although you might have a dozen users on your site, all of whom are using a session variable, they cannot interact with one another. Each user (and by that I mean the code running) can only access their own session variables. If you want them to be able to see each other, it has to be done via an intermediary device such as a database, or a file - or an actual application that is constantly running - written in Java or C# or the like, which is ALWAYS running and being passed data from the PHP code.

So basically, although you can apply AJAX to check constantly for the updates, the data in the background is pretty much always done via a simple table that you can implement either on page reload or get a bit fancier and check it on a regular basis via scripts running inside your page.

Comment: That makes sense with not being able to use it for SESSION_[ID] as it is unique. So basically, I need to write up some php to make it where once a user is logged in/out they can view members profiles and their status (online/offline) - then use either ajax calls or javascript to refresh that specific data in real-time to perform correctly. Of which the ajax calls or javascript is also being triggered upon the php functions that are being queried when a member logs in/out.  I think I get the gist of it now, I just don't know how to implement any of that unfortunately, any ideas on how to start?